# Macro for copying and increment date value in excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to generate data like below in excel.

```
2/8/2013
2/8/2013
2/8/2013
2/8/2013
2/8/2013
2/8/2013
2/9/2013
2/9/2013
2/9/2013
2/9/2013
2/9/2013
2/9/2013
2/10/2013
2/10/2013
2/10/2013
2/10/2013
2/10/2013
```

A date value in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` and the same on 6 rows...In the 7th it should be incremented and continued till 12th row like that the sequence should be repeated.

Could any of excel users help me in writing a formula/macro etc... for this?

Thanks in advance,
Chandu

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you already have first Date stored in `A1`, type in `A2` the following formula: `=IF(MOD(ROW(),6)=1,A1+1,A1)` and autofill down as required. Format resulted cells as `Date` with required pattern.

Comment: +1 Same solution, but you were 49" earlier! ;-)

Comment: @PeterAlbert nothing more than a luck, Peter!)

Comment: Damn it pals, you're soooo quick) that dinner tea cost me an answer)))) my +1 for both of you)

Comment: + 1 for both of you guys... Keep up the good work :)

Comment: that Excel thread is becoming more and more looks like a crazy race of the team of fanatics)))) I won't surprise if soon we'll provide correct answers within a minute after a question was submitted.

Comment: +1 .....but I would suggest a small change - use `ROWS` instead of `ROW` - if you do that then if you insert rows at the top of the worksheet you still get 6 of each date (that won't happen using ROW on its own), i.e. `=A1+(MOD(ROWS(A$2:A2),6)=0)`

Comment: @barryhoudini this worth an answer and fair upvote. I'm sure for OP this is one-time solution, but for me that was useful for future use.

Comment: But I'm seeing all '######' after 49th row...Would you be able to explain that?

Comment: @ChanduMaddila try to adjust column width - make it wider

Answer (score 3):

1. Type in your start date in cell A1.
2. Format it according to your needs, i.e. use the Format Cells dialog and select the date format.
3. In cell A2, enter the following formula:

   ```
   =IF(MOD(ROW(A2),6)=1,A1+1,A1)
   ```
4. Copy this formula down to where you need it

Comment: Strange, but `ROW(2)` doesn't work for me...

Comment: Typo! Meant `A2`. Corrected now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code :

```
Sub test()
    Dim dt As Date
    dt = Date

    For i = 1 To 1000

        If (i Mod 6 = 0) Then
            dt = DateAdd("d", 1, dt)
        End If


        Range("A" & i).Value = Format(dt, "MM/dd/yyyy")
    Next
End Sub
```